# Office Script to do SHA256 to 2 column on a table failed after 1 row

Tags: excel, office-scripts

I'm trying to use a code I found here to encode 2 columns in a table in my excel. However, it'll only work on 1 row and then gives a "An unexpected error occurred. Close the task pane to try again."

I'm super new to office script. And I hope you can help. What am I doing wrong?

```js
async function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
    
    let selectedSheet = workbook.getWorksheet("Sheet1");
    let usedRange = selectedSheet.getUsedRange();
    let lastRow = usedRange.getLastRow().getRowIndex();

    for (let i = 1; i <= lastRow; i++) {
      let mobile = await shahash(usedRange.getCell(i, 1) as unknown as string);
      let mail = await shahash(usedRange.getCell(i, 2) as unknown as string);
      usedRange.getCell(i, 1).setValue(mobile);
      usedRange.getCell(i, 2).setValue(mail);
    }
}

async function shahash(message: string) {
  // encode as UTF-8
  const msgBuffer = new TextEncoder().encode(message);

  // hash the message
  const hashBuffer = await crypto.subtle.digest('SHA-256', msgBuffer);

  // convert ArrayBuffer to Array
  const hashArray = Array.from(new Uint8Array(hashBuffer));


  // convert bytes to hex string                  
  const hashHex = hashArray.map(b => b.toString(16).padStart(2, '0')).join('')
  return hashHex;
}
```

I'm really not sure what else I can try. Just want it to go through the whole table and convert that 2 columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- `getCell` returns a range object. Use `getText()` to get the content of a cell.

```js
    let mobile = await shahash(usedRange.getCell(i, 1).getText());
    let mail = await shahash(usedRange.getCell(i, 2).getText());
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I knew that part looked a bit weird. It worked!

Now I have a different problem which I'm not sure if I should make a new post.

The script now works if I trigger it in Excel. However, if I trigger it through Power Automate flow, it throws this error.

"message": "We were unable to run the script. Please try again.\nRuntime error: Line 17: TextEncoder is not defined\r\nclientRequestId: c52a8514-0673-4e56-ae41-2cb7c1c4a67f",

Not sure if anybody else can help :)

Comment: [What is the the best way to ask follow up questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266767/what-is-the-the-best-way-to-ask-follow-up-questions)